# App Crashes when using pushing from UINavigationController, JSON TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am going to try to explain my issue the better I can.

So I have a UINavigationController. Inside I have a UITableView using JSON to get a list of arrays. When the user presses on a cell, it takes them to the detail view, where there I have a new view with information and UITableView that displays a new array from JSON. Each view has its own URL with different data. Now, the issue that the app crashes when I push on the detail view. It loads at first but then it crashes. If I remove the code to display the tableview and all the JSON stuff, it works just fine. The code is well written as far as I know. I created a whole new page using the same code of the first view where is the main tableview, and it still crashes. I have no idea why. From top of my head, it looks like the app doesn't allow me to use a new tableView with its data from the web using JSON but it does allow me to use it on my main view.

Ok, now, here are the codes I'm getting when it crashes (The codes are not always the same):

This the line where is crashing at:

```
        cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Series"];
```

I get all these crashes each time I build the app over and over again:

1: THREAD : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5000000c)

2: THREAD : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)

3: THREAD : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x41c8000c)

4: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
And the console log:

[image]

and this one too:

[image]

And the codes keep coming on and on.

This is the code I use to call the URL:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http//MYURL.com/%@blahblah%d",fullDate, [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] / -60];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: NSLog the contents of news and post here.

Comment: I can't even NSLog "news". :( It crashes as well with the same code. Any ideas?

Comment: I just don't understand why it works fine on the first view and on the detail view it crashes.

Comment: Seems to me like both crashes are at the same point in DetailScheduleViewController.  Clearly you're using a zombie object on that line.

Comment: What is a zombie object?

Comment: Just what it sounds like.  A dead object "walking" around.  (Because you're using a pointer to an object that's been deallocated and then reallocated as something else.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `news` object is being deallocated prematurely. Check to make sure your keeping a strong reference to it (strong for arc, otherwise use retain). The memory that used to store your `news` is clearly being used by some `CALayer` now, and since `CALayer` does not respond to `objectAtIndex:`, your program is crashing. Use Zombies to find when your `news` object is actually being deallocated.